# "Can't play this video" alert message appears when there is no Ad

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am playing the Ad first and then the actual video content on the native android mediaPlayer.But, If ad is not present, I get the alert dialog with the message as above and then the video plays.This makes the user feel that there is no video itself.Once,the dialog appears he goes back.I tried with the following code but with no avail...

```
mAdVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.d("video", "setOnErrorListener ");
            return true;
        }
    });   



private void playAds() {
    mMediaController.playAds(RequestSettings.INSERTION_POINT_TYPE_ON_BEFORE_CONTENT,
            new AdSlotCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdSlotCompletion() {
                    try {
                        mMediaController.resumePlayer();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        AndroidUtils.showToast(getString(R.string.no_video), PlayerBrightCoveActivity.this);
                    }

                }
            });

}
```

Comment: give exception where you get ad video, not in videoview

Comment: the code you give us is for handle error in video view. show us the code where you get ad video

Comment: I have edited it...please take a look...

Comment: you already catch it here with `AndroidUtils.showToast(getString(R.string.no_video), PlayerBrightCoveActivity.this);` if you dont want to tell the user if there's no ad video, then dont toast it